# How to create Unit Test (include Database) in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

Here's my code :

```
public partial class ActivityService
    {
        public SearchActivityOutput GetActivityFromDbByName(SearchActivityInput input)
        {
            using (var conn = DbService.GetInstance().GetOpenConnection())
            {
                var savedActivities = GetSearchResultByNameQuery.GetInstance()
                    .Execute(conn, new { Name = input.Name });

                var activityList = savedActivities.Select(a => new ActivityDetail()
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    City = a.City,
                    Country = a.Country,
                    Description = a.Description,
                    OperationTime = a.OperationTime,
                    Price = a.Price
                }).ToList();

                var output = new SearchActivityOutput
                {
                    ActivityList = activityList
                };

                return output;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i create unit test from that class?

my sample unit test for that class:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void GetActivityFromDbByNameTest()
        {
            Initializer.Init();

            var input = new SearchActivityInput { Name = "Marjan" };

            var ActList1 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan", City = "Bandung", Country = "Indonesia", Description = "coba", OperationTime = "24 Jam", Price = 2000};
            var ActList2 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan", City = "Bandung", Country = "Indonesia", Description = "coba", OperationTime = "24 Jam", Price = 3500 };
            var ActList3 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan aja", City = "Jakarta", Country = "Indonesia", Description = "apapun", OperationTime = "2 Hari", Price = 4500 };
            var ActList4 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan", City = "Stockholm", Country = "Swedia", Description = "123coba", OperationTime = "3 Jam", Price = 3500 };
            var ActList5 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan", City = "Stockholm", Country = "Swedia", Description = "123coba", OperationTime = "3 Jam", Price = 4500 };
            var ActList6 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan aja", City = "Jakarta", Country = "Indonesia", Description = "apapun", OperationTime = "2 Hari", Price = 2000 };
            var ActList7 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan", City = "Stockholm", Country = "Swedia", Description = "123coba", OperationTime = "3 Jam", Price = 3500 };
            var ActList8 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan", City = "Stockholm", Country = "Swedia", Description = "123coba", OperationTime = "3 Jam", Price = 2000 };
            var ActList9 = new ActivityDetail()
                { Name = "Marjan", City = "Stockholm", Country = "Swedia", Description = "123coba", OperationTime = "3 Jam", Price = 2000 };
            var ActList = new List<ActivityDetail>();
            ActList.Add(ActList1);
            ActList.Add(ActList2);
            ActList.Add(ActList3);
            ActList.Add(ActList4);
            ActList.Add(ActList5);
            ActList.Add(ActList6);
            ActList.Add(ActList7);
            ActList.Add(ActList8);
            ActList.Add(ActList9);
            var expectedResult = new SearchActivityOutput
            {
                ActivityList = ActList
            };
            using (var conn = DbService.GetInstance().GetOpenConnection())
            {
                var actualResult = ActivityService.GetInstance().GetActivityFromDbByName(input);
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
            }

        }
```

but, when i run the unit test, there give some error message :

> Test Name:    GetActivityFromDbByNameTest Test
>
> Result StackTrace:    at
>   xxxx.ActivityServiceTests.GetActivityFromDbByNameTest()
>   in
>
> 70 Result Message:    Assert.AreEqual failed.
>   Expected:(xxx.yyy.zzz.Model.SearchActivityOutput).
>   Actual:(xxx.yyy.zzz.Model.SearchActivityOutput).

Comment: Have you debugged the test to see why it failed? You are doing `Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult)` but those aren't equal. Stick a breakpoint on this line, and debug through it to see where the actual is different to what you expect.

Comment: @Stuart How to stick a breakpoint? i have set breakpoint, but when i run the unit test, the program not break on breakpoint.

Comment: You need to debug the test, not run the test. So put a break point on the test on the assert line, then via test Runner right click on the test and select debug.

Comment: @Stuart ok, i'll try. thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unit test a class that performs any I/O-related tasks. Even if your tests seem to run fine on your development machine, they will likely fail on your colleague's machine or CI server.

In order for your piece of code to be testable, it should be a either a pure function, or it should be reducible to a pure function using some abstraction techniques like IoC / higher order functions / etc.

Learn to write testable code first. This article will give you some advise - https://www.toptal.com/resume/sergey-kolodiy (I'm the author of it).

Comment: Thank you very mush, sir. Nice article. I hope learn more about ASP.NET (C#) from your articles.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the database while your unittesting.

Wikipedia says: A common example of this is classes that depend on a database: in order to test the class, the tester often writes code that interacts with the database. This is a mistake, because a unit test should usually not go outside of its own class boundary, and especially should not cross such process/network boundaries because this can introduce unacceptable performance problems to the unit test-suite.

Use testdata or a dummy class that represent your Database.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119367/should-service-test-classes-connect-to-the-database

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/138238/unit-testing-database-coupled-app/138257#138257

Comment: I agree, but maybe he's trying to write integration tests to test his service layer...

Comment: can you give some example about unit test related to database?

Comment: there are no examples about unittest interact with databases, because no body do that. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119367/should-service-test-classes-connect-to-the-database answer to a similar question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/138257

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the other statements about not using the database in your unit tests, but the answer to the failure that you're currently receiving is that you should be using methods of the CollectionAssert class to compare the contents of two collections instead of the Assert class that you're using.  If you just want to ensure that the returned List contains the same elements regardless of ordering, you can use

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedResult, actualResult);
```

If sequencing order is important, you should use

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
```

Comment: what the different between `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` and `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` ?

Comment: I think what you meant is what is the difference between CollectionAssert.AreEqual and CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent.  AreEquivalent ensures that the same elements are present (no more, no less), but does not require them to be in the same order within the collections. AreEqual requires the same elements to be present *and* in the same order